# Cannot connect browser to Karma server (permanent page loading)

Tags: angular, karma-runner

I am starting Karma using IntelliJ. Everything looks fine, new Chrome window pops up, but it keeps loading forever.

Karma log:

```
17 07 2018 13:29:01.754:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9877/
17 07 2018 13:29:01.758:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
17 07 2018 13:29:01.773:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome

 10% building modules 1/3 modules 2 active …ts\rafa-components-lib\src\polyfills.ts
 10% building modules 2/3 modules 1 active …ts\rafa-components-lib\src\polyfills.ts
 75% basic chunk optimization EnsureChunkConditionsPlugin
 75% basic chunk optimization RemoveParentModulesPlugin
 88% hashing
 90% additional chunk assets processing
 92% after chunk asset optimization SourceMapDevToolPlugin main.js generate SourceMap
Waiting for a captured browser... To capture a browser open http://localhost:9877/
```

Accessing localhost:9877 results in permanent loading. Sometimes it works as expected (karma starts and browser is connected) but it is kind of random.

Maybe someone have an idea what is going on??

Karma config:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9877,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

New browser window:
[image]

Connection is established:
[image]

Comment: 1) Project is brand new (issue on older, bigger projects as well) 2) I have updated Karma from 1.7* to latest (issue on both versions) 3) I have tried with Firefox - same result. I also tried to open RAW connection to listening port using putty but i got "connection refused". Firewall is off.... I had to kill all Node.js processes and start again - this helped. But issue will came back for sure in short time as it happened before.

Comment: I think it is Karma issue (or even environment). Happened to me on Angular 5 and 6 with Karma 1.7 and latest (2.*)

Comment: I've having the same problem. Were you able to fix it??

Comment: @Manoj nope, its still open

Comment: Ok i've fixed the problem. For me it was hanging in IntelliJ but working in ng test. And in ng test i was finding some compilation issues in my test files. When i fixed them, it started working in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 8):

The same problem occurred to me in Webstorm.

I had a compilation problem in my tests, in my case it was `ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'.`.

In the Webstorm console the error was only shown after the browser had failed to be captured the third time. When you run `ng test`, you will instantly see the compilation error. After resolving it, the tests ran in Webstorm just fine.

Comment: Yep. ng test really shows compilation error, while running Karma server didn't show anything. Worked for me too.
I wonder is there a way to run specs compillation everytime before Karma launches tests?

Comment: Indeed. Strange it has been +2 years now, and the issue is exactly the same. I guess that I have learned how to live with it anyway ;)